# What it the easiest way to make LINQ to process all collection at once?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I often have similar constructions:

```
var t = from i in Enumerable.Range(0,5)
        select num(i);

Console.WriteLine(t.Count());
foreach (var item in t)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

In this case LINQ will evaluate `num()` function twice for each element (one for Count() and one for output). So after such LINQ calls I have to declare new vatiable: `var t2 = t.ToList();`

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `ToList` without making a separate variable:

```
var t = Enumerable.Range(0,5).Select(num).ToList();
```

**EDIT**: Or,

```
var t = Enumerable.Range(0,5).Select(x => num(x)).ToList();
```

Or even

```
var t = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0,5)
         select num).ToList();
```

Comment: @Aliostad: Your answer is totally wrong.  A `Select` call does not involve any lists.

Comment: Select has a loop in it, I bet.

Comment: @Aliostad: **You are wrong**.  It doesn't.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx

Comment: And what if I don't like to write queries as functions?

Comment: @Poma: Then you can use any other kind of `Select` call.

Comment: oh, the last one looks ugly but it seems I have to use that one. Thought that there may be more elegant solution.

Comment: @Poma: Why do you think you have to use it?

Comment: because I usually write my queries in `from x in y select z` form and not like `y.Select(z)`

Comment: You might want to consider switching to method syntax.

Comment: Method calls don't require ugly parentheses.  You should use whatever syntax you like most.

Answer (score 1):

I usually call the functions so it could look like this:

var t = Enumerable.Range(0,5).Select(x=>num(x)).ToList();

Comment: virtual -1. This is 2 queries! One for select, on for ToList.

Comment: @Aliostad: No, the ToList() iterates through the Select()'s enumerable and inserts each resulting item (the result of evaluating num()) into a List. One "query". Once you have these values, you no longer need to evaluate num() (which is apparently nontrivial). In addition, the Count() extension method on a List simply returns List.Count instead of enumerating through the List. What does still happen is that there are two iterations through the result set; one to put them into the List (which evaluates all the num() calls up front) and the other in the foreach on the List.

Comment: question was how to make sure num was only evaluated once per item in the range, not the most efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
...

var count = 0
foreach(var item in t)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item)
   count++;
}
```

num is now evaluated once per item. If you wanted to use the predicate overload (Count(i=>i.PropA == "abc")) then just wrap the increment in an if. Don't use extension methods for everything; like you realized, just because you can't see the implementation doesn't mean it isn't still costing you.

If you expect to use the concrete values a lot, then ToList() is a great answer.